# Encoding information by hiding digits

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, contest-math

Good evening,

I have been stumbled by this problem.

Two magicians, call them A and B, play a trick: while B is not looking, A asks a spectator to write an n-digit number on a board. A then cancels two digits. B comes back, being able to see the remaining n-2 digits, in order, and the positions of the two cancelled digits. He guesses, correctly, the two cancelled digits in order. For which n is this possible?

An easy induction can prove that if the trick works for $n$, it works for all numbers greater than $n$. I have found a way to make it work for $n = 20$: supposing the sum of the first $10$ digits is $k \mod10$ and the sum of the other $10$ digits is $l \mod 10$, A just hides the $k$-th and $(10+l)$-th digit.

However, I have not been able to prove this is a lower bound. In fact, the "natural" argument leads me to think the true bound is $n \geq 15$: there are $10^n$ possible numbers, and $b$ can receive $10^{(n-2)}{{n}\choose{2}}$ different strings. For the trick to work, we then need ${{n}\choose{2}} \geq 100$ which implies $n \geq 15$.

Is there a way to explicitly construct the algorithm for the trick in case $n = 15$?
This is a variation of a well-known problem, which has already been asked about and answered on this site, in which the cancelled digits are adjacent, which results, much more easily, in $n \geq 101$.

Edit: I think the most straightforward solution is to forsake every hope of an explicit construction and apply Hall's marriage theorem (this is akin to finding a perfect matching on the bipartite graph between the set of numbers and the set of strings with two numbers hidden, and this graph satisfies the marriage condition by a double counting argument). I have thus proven that $15$ is the lower bound, but still have not been able to describe the strategy for $15 \leq n < 20$

Edit 2: The magicians are collaborating (there would be no solution if they were not), the spectator is not

Comment: Should say:  this is a nice trick.  What is the source?

Comment: Anyway, this is a variation of a problem I found in "Olympiad combinatorics" by Pranav Sriram, which he vaguely attributes to "Russia"

Comment: @carfog  Can you provide the link to the "well known variant"?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1439430/algorithm-to-uniquely-determine-a-number-using-two-adjacent-digits?rq=1

Comment: Maybe you should try a simpler problem first? Say the spectator chooses an $n$-bit *binary* number. The same logic implies $\binom{n}2\ge 2^2\implies n\ge 4$, so try to find a strategy for A and B then (spoiler: it is possible). Next, try to succeed with an $n$-digit ternary number for the minimal $n=5$ (I do not know the answer).

Comment: Also, see https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/12284/magician-assistant-nine-dice-and-two-cups for a solution for base six with the minimal $n=9$. In this case, $\binom{9}2=6^2$ exactly, so the strategy necessarily fits together perfectly.

Comment: @MikeEarnest thanks! Solved it

Comment: @carfog You should write in the question that the two magicians are cooperating, since that's not so obvious the way you worded it.

Comment: @dxiv done. I had assumed it was obvious from the fact they were playing a trick on the spectator